# Inserting BigDecimal numbers into ArrayList in java

Tags: java, data-structures

How can I insert `BigDecimal` values into an `ArrayList` using java?
First i declare a bigdecimal number(here it is 0) as shown below.
and after that I need to insert this bigdecimal value 'unit' into an arraylist.My code snippet is shown below.

```
BigDecimal unit = new BigDecimal(0);
int x=0;
int y=10;

while(x<10){

    // Here i need to insert the `BigDecimal` value "unit" into an `ArrayList` for each iteration of this loop

    x++;
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything that we can use to start with?

Comment: What is the problem in inserting? could you post some code to help us understand

Comment: Give useful information about your problem!

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what your problem is?

Comment: Please add your code snippet for a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Use [List.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-):

```
List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
BigDecimal totalQuantity = new BigDecimal(0);
list.add(totalQuantity);
```

Comment: You should use `List#add(int, E)`, which inserts at a specific position instead of just adding at the end.

Comment: @Bubletan: I might have missed something, but I didn't see anything in the question saying that we needed to add at a specific location.

Comment: @fzzfzzfzz Well, just thought as he didn't say it should be added at the end. Inserting in general means that you can add it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(80.6 + 379.6);
460.20000000000005

System.out.println(BigDecimal(80.6 + 379.6));
460.200000000000045474735088646411895751953125
```

There are multiple numbers where Java is doing this. Unable to fix and get the programs running correctly, making some of my mathematical programs fail.

Tried in multiple to see if it was a compiler issue.

There may be a bug?